# Buffer geometry based sprites

Tags: three.js

My experiment calls for a large number of  textured 'sprites' that can be both positioned *and* rotated independently. Since the number is large, I'd like to do it with buffer geometry.

It works well with the current setup that uses THREE.PointCloud and a material with an image map but as far as I understand it, each particle can only be resized and/or positioned but not rotated.

Before I dive in and see if I can create the buffer geom by hand along with requisite UVs etc, I wanted to check if there was already an example of this already - I didn't see anything in the list of threejs.org examples - or a better way to do this.

Comment: You can create your own `ShaderMaterial` and apply the rotation in the fragment shader. See, for example, https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1891#issuecomment-5923058

Comment: That looks very promising - thank you.

Comment: @speedwell: I am new to Three.js and trying to achieve the same stuff you mentioned here. I could not understand much from the above link. Can you redirect me to some example of this?